# Which is the Electrolyse Reaction?

Tags: electrolysis

$$\ce{NaOH +H2O->H2 +O2 +NaOH}$$
We know that $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ go  to the cathode and anode, but how can I write the total reaction?
Is it: $$\ce{2NaOH +2H2O->2H2 +O2 +2NaOH}$$
I've put NaOH both sides because if the mass of NaOH is given, how can I find the mass of H2 for example?

Comment: Why would you need to write $\ce{NaOH}$ on both sides?

Comment: Because if I'm given the mass of NaOH, how should I find the mass of other substances?

Answer (score 1):

Electrolyse of water is a redox reaction, meaning that there is a transfer of electrons between atoms. Now, every redox reaction can be written as a combination of 2 **half-equations**. One half-equation shows one species getting oxidised (losing electrons) and the other half-equation shows the other species getting reduced (gaining electrons). When you combine these two half-equations you get the **overall reaction**, which is what you are asking for. Here is guide that should help you find the overall equation of any redox equation, not just this one example.

**Step 1: Determine what species gets oxidised and species gets reduced**

Now, what I think the reaction you are trying to describe is the electrolyse of water. **Correct me if I am wrong.** If that is the case, there is no need for $\ce{NaOH}$ in the equation as it appears on both side, meaning that they cancel each other out (also $\ce{NaOH}$ has nothing to do with electrolyse of water). Secondly, it is $\ce{H2O}$ that gets oxidised and reduced, not $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$.

**Step 2: Determine  half-equations**

These can be easily found by using your table of standard reduction potentials. Oxidation half-equation: $$\ce{2H2O -> O2 + 4H+ + 4e-}$$
Reduction half-equation: $$\ce{2H2O + 2e- -> H2 +2OH-}$$

**Step 3: Balance each equation so that there is the same number of electrons**

We can't immediately add the half-equations as the electrons won't cancel each other out. This means that we need to multiply the reduction half-equation by 2:$$\ce{4H2O + 4e- -> 2H2 +4OH-}$$

**Step 4: Add the half-equations**

When you add each half-equation, you get: $$\ce{6H2O   -> 2H2 + O2 + 4H+ + 4OH-}$$ The $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ combine to form water which then cancel out with the water the other side. Therefore the overall reaction is: $$\ce{2H2O  -> 2H2 + O2}$$

Comment: What if I am given the mass of NaOH, how am I supposed to find the mass of other elements?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. How is NaOH related to the electrolysis of water? Can you explain your problem in more detail?